# Find the eigenvalues for an ODE

Tags: differential-equations

For example, say I have $y'' + \lambda y = 0$ and the endpoint conditions are $y'(0) = 0$ and $y'(\pi) = 0$.

How can I find the values for $\lambda$ that for which there is a non-trivial ($y\neq0$) solution using Mathematica?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution gives

```
de = y''[x] + lam y[x] == 0;
sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[{ode}, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Taking derivative and applying boundary conditions gives

```
yd = D[sol, x];
eq1 = (yd /. x -> 0) == 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eq2 = (yd /. x -> Pi) == 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From first equation, only choice is `C[2]=0` hence the second equation becomes

```
eq3 = eq2 /. C[2] -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now for `C[1]` not to be zero (else trivial solution) then either $\lambda=0$ or $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda} \pi)=0$. We do not want $\lambda=0$ so the only choice left is $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda} \pi)=0$ which happens when $\sqrt{\lambda} \pi=n \pi$ for integer $n$.

So Mathematica choose $n=0$ and hence $\sqrt{\lambda} \pi=0$ which means $\lambda=0$ but this is not possible, so only choice is `C[1]` is zero. Hence the trivial solution.

To force $n$ to be something other than zero,

```
 Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n != 0 && (Sqrt[lam] Pi) == n Pi, 
      Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {C[1], C[2]}, Reals]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So there are the conditions

update: I should say, if I was doing this by hand, I will just write at the end above that $\sqrt{\lambda} \pi = m \pi$ for $m \neq 0$ and $m$ integers. Hence just say that $\lambda=m^2$.  This does give the same conditions as well as above:

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n != 0 && lam == n^2, 
  Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {C[1], C[2]}, Reals]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The bottom line, is that Mathematica gave trivial solution, since it saw `Sin[x]==0` and just said `x=0`

Answer (score 6):

```
sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[{y''[x] + lam y[x] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], x]
sol2 = Solve[(D[sol, x] /. x -> Pi ) == 0 && lam != 0 && C[1] != 0, lam, Reals]
FindSequenceFunction@ Most[Union @@ Table[lam /. sol2 /. C[2] -> x, {x, 0, 20}]]

(*
C[1] Cos[Sqrt[lam] x]

{{lam -> ConditionalExpression[4 C[2]^2, C[2] ∈ Integers && C[2] >= 1]}, 
 {lam -> ConditionalExpression[1 + 4 C[2] + 4 C[2]^2, C[2] ∈ Integers && C[2] >= 0]}}

#1^2 &
```

*)

So `lam` must be a squared integer.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the proper formulation of the problem, assuming `C[1] == C[2] == 0` corresponds to the trivial solution, is

```
Exists[{C[1], C[2]}, bcs && (C[2] != 0 || C[1] != 0) /. gensol]
```

where `bcs` are the boundary conditions and `gensol` is the general solution.

The OP's case:

```
gensol = First@DSolve[y''[x] + λ y[x] == 0, y, x];
bcs = y'[0] == 0 && y'[π] == 0;

Resolve[Exists[{C[1], C[2]}, bcs && (C[2] != 0 || C[1] != 0) /. gensol], Reals]
Solve[Simplify[%], λ]
(*
λ == 0 || λ == 0 || λ == 0 || λ == 0 ||
 (C[3] ∈ Integers && C[3] >= 0 && λ == 1 + 4 C[3] + 4 C[3]^2) ||
 (C[3] ∈ Integers && C[3] >= 1 && λ == 4 C[3]^2)

{{λ -> ConditionalExpression[4 C[3]^2, 
    C[3] ∈ Integers && C[3] >= 1]},
 {λ -> ConditionalExpression[1 + 4 C[3] + 4 C[3]^2, 
    C[3] ∈ Integers && C[3] >= 0]},
 {λ -> 0}}
*)
```

I can't get *Mathematica* to combine the odd and even nonnegative integers into a single solution.  One could resort to [belisarius's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius) method of using `FindSequenceFunction`, which works in the OP's case.